# Honeycomb app, LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing an app for Android 3.x and want to use LocalBroadcastManager. However, it is not available in the default Android 3.x SDK but only in the Android support package.

Do I just use the one from the support package instead?

p.s The same question can also apply for ViewPager, the control does not exist unless you include the Android support package into your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, LocalBroadcastManager is currently only available in the Support Package. It looks like that is the case with ViewPager as well. It's easy to add the Support Package to your app. More details on that [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#SettingUp).

Comment: Ok well, I will have to go that route then :)